# Vertically center images with varying heights

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to add a style that vertically centers images in a certain div when each image has different dimensions?

If all the images were the same height I'd just use `margin-top:-<half the height of the image>px` but as I don't know the heights I'm a bit stuck

Comment: Does my answer answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:
 - put the height dimension inside the img tag
 - create an image loader, once all the images are loaded call your resize function

Comment: Aesthetic information on markup is generally a no-no, and this solution could really use some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the css method:

```
#item{
    background: url('some/url/img.jpg') center center;
}
```

Offcourse you can alter the centers to left/right/top/bottom (and I believe there is a middle). No calculating or tricky javascript/css or sloppy/hard-to-understand code :)

[Some info about background-position on W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

Comment: I initially started with this, but the problem comes when the image isn't quite as wide as the browser it has borders on either side

Comment: That was not in your topic :P And also, that is also the case if you place an image normally. Unless you want to stretch the sizes, which is something I try to avoid as much as possible

Comment: @DeanElliott ~ If you're planning on hitting supporting browsers, you can fix that by specifying [`background-size:100%;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: If I was only targetting CSS3 browsers then I'd have used `background-size` straight away. I'm only looking for a jQuery solution here

Comment: I've been trying to apply this to websites (i.e. www.sparnaaij-juweliers.nl) and found it it's somewhat difficult, especially on resize and load in IE8 (dont know about the higher ones)

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

does what you want to do.

Here using the css method,

http://jsfiddle.net/m8mNf/4/

Here using jQuery method,

http://jsfiddle.net/cq2S8/351/

Example using jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Center my iamges</title>
<style>
body {
    padding:0;margin:0;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("img").css('vertical-align','middle');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Hello
    <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/13900000/The-Rose-of-Love-roses-13967150-1024-768.jpg" width="60" height="50">
    <img src="http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/13900000/The-Rose-of-Love-roses-13967150-1024-768.jpg" width="60" height="80">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.